# Prove that $x^n-1\ge n(x-1)x^{\frac{(n-1)}{2}}$ for all $x\ge 1$

Tags: inequality

Prove that $x^n-1\ge n(x-1)x^{\frac{(n-1)}{2}}$ for all $x\ge 1$.

I canceled out $(x-1)$ from both sides and tried to prove $1+x^2+x^3+...+x^{n-1} \ge n x^\frac{(n-1)}{2}$ by induction.but I could not proceed further.how to solve it?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positive $x$ you can use the AM-GM inequality:

$$\frac{1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1}}{n} \ge \sqrt[n]{ x^{ \frac{n(n-1)}{2} } } = x^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$$